# show total based on quantity and display total,item name,Rate etc

Tags: android, if-statement, android-intent, bundle, calculation

This is the code for check the quantity value is empty else do the calculation

```
 ordernew.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
    
                    if (addordernew.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                        addordernew.requestFocus();
                        addordernew.setError("Quantity is not Entered");
    
                    } else {
    
                        if(getstock.getText().toString().equals("Stove Top Stuffing"))
                        {
                            ShowItem.setText("Stove Top Stuffing");
                            
                            Showqty.setText(addordernew.getText().toString());
                            ShowRate.setText(rategiven.getText().toString());
                        }
    
                        if(getstock.getText().toString().equals("Campell's Soup"))
                        {
                            ShowItem.setText("Campell's Soup");
                            Showqty.setText(addordernew.getText().toString());
                            ShowRate.setText(rategiven.getText().toString());
                        }
    
                        if(getstock.getText().toString().equals("Tide"))
                        {
                            ShowItem.setText("Tide");
                            Showqty.setText(addordernew.getText().toString());
                            ShowRate.setText(rategiven.getText().toString());
                        }
    
                        if(getstock.getText().toString().equals("Pampers"))
                        {
                            ShowItem.setText("Pampers");
                            Showqty.setText(addordernew.getText().toString());
                            ShowRate.setText(rategiven.getText().toString());
                        }
    
                        if(getstock.getText().toString().equals("Pepsi Products"))
                        {
                            ShowItem.setText("Pepsi Products");
                            Showqty.setText(addordernew.getText().toString());
                            ShowRate.setText(rategiven.getText().toString());
                        }
    
                        if(getstock.getText().toString().equals("Tang"))
                        {
                            ShowItem.setText("Tang");
                            Showqty.setText(addordernew.getText().toString());
                            ShowRate.setText(rategiven.getText().toString());
                        }
    
                        if(getstock.getText().toString().equals("Top Ramen"))
                        {
                            ShowItem.setText("Top Ramen");
                            Showqty.setText(addordernew.getText().toString());
                            ShowRate.setText(rategiven.getText().toString());
                        }
    
                        if(getstock.getText().toString().equals("Knorr"))
                        {
                            ShowItem.setText("Knorr");
                            Showqty.setText(addordernew.getText().toString());
                            ShowRate.setText(rategiven.getText().toString());
                        }
    
                        if(getstock.getText().toString().equals("Palmolive"))
                        {
                            ShowItem.setText("Palmolive");
                            Showqty.setText(addordernew.getText().toString());
                            ShowRate.setText(rategiven.getText().toString());
                        }
    
                        if(getstock.getText().toString().equals("Scotch-Brite"))
                        {
                            ShowItem.setText("Scotch-Brite");
                            Showqty.setText(addordernew.getText().toString());
                            ShowRate.setText(rategiven.getText().toString());
                        }
    
                        if(getstock.getText().toString().equals("Bounty Paper Towls"))
                        {
                            ShowItem.setText("Bounty Paper Towls");
                            Showqty.setText(addordernew.getText().toString());
                            ShowRate.setText(rategiven.getText().toString());
                        }
    
    
    
                        if(getstock.getText().toString().equals("Oreo Cookies"))
                        {
                            ShowItem.setText("Oreo Cookies");
                            Showqty.setText(addordernew.getText().toString());
                            ShowRate.setText(rategiven.getText().toString());
                        }
    
    
                        if(getstock.getText().toString().equals("Quaker Oats"))
                        {
                            ShowItem.setText("Quaker Oats");
                            Showqty.setText(addordernew.getText().toString());
                            ShowRate.setText(rategiven.getText().toString());
                        }
    
                        if(getstock.getText().toString().equals("Lays Potato Chips"))
                        {
                            ShowItem.setText("Lays Potato Chips");
                            Showqty.setText(addordernew.getText().toString());
                            ShowRate.setText(rategiven.getText().toString());
                        }
    
    
                        //  ShowItem.setText("Stove Top Stuffing");
                        //Showqty.setText(addordernew.getText().toString());
                       // ShowRate.setText(rategiven.getText().toString());
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Order Taken", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
```

this is the code for the tax rate and percentage calculation

```
  getstock.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(AddOrder.this, ListItem.class);
              Intent intent = getIntent();
               Bundle bd = intent.getExtras();
                if (bd != null) {
                    String getname = (String) bd.get("position");
                    getstock.setText(getname);
                    System.out.println(getname);


                   if(getstock.getText().toString().equals("Stove Top Stuffing")) {
                       taxgiven.setText("12");
                        stockgiven.setText("250");
                        rategiven.setText("598.214");
                        MRPRate.setText("999");


                       //Showqty.setText(addorder.getText().toString());
                       // ShowRate.setText(TaxInclrate.getText().toString());

                        //percentage calculation
                       double taxamount = Double.parseDouble(taxgiven.getText().toString());
                       double rateamount = Double.parseDouble(rategiven.getText().toString());
                       Double result = ((double)Math.round(rateamount* taxamount) / 100);
                       Double finalamount=(result + rateamount);
                       TaxInclrate.setText(""+finalamount);

                                          }
                   else if(getstock.getText().toString().equals("Campell's Soup"))
                   {
                       taxgiven.setText("5");
                       stockgiven.setText("100");
                       rategiven.setText("150");
                       MRPRate.setText("456");

                       //percentage calculation
                       double taxamount = Double.parseDouble(taxgiven.getText().toString());
                       double rateamount = Double.parseDouble(rategiven.getText().toString());
                       Double result = ((double)rateamount* taxamount) / 100;
                       Double finalamount=(result + rateamount);
                       TaxInclrate.setText(""+finalamount);
                   }
                   else if(getstock.getText().toString().equals("Tide"))
                   {
                       taxgiven.setText("5");
                       String a=taxgiven.getText().toString();
                       stockgiven.setText("50");
                       rategiven.setText("200");
                       MRPRate.setText("1000");

                       //percentage calculation
                       double taxamount = Double.parseDouble(taxgiven.getText().toString());
                       double rateamount = Double.parseDouble(rategiven.getText().toString());
                       Double result = ((double)rateamount* taxamount) / 100;
                       Double finalamount=(result + rateamount);
                       TaxInclrate.setText(""+finalamount);
                   }
                   else if(getstock.getText().toString().equals("Pampers"))
                   {
                         taxgiven.setText("5");
                       stockgiven.setText("25");
                       rategiven.setText("100");
                       MRPRate.setText("1234");

                       //percentage calculation
                       double taxamount = Double.parseDouble(taxgiven.getText().toString());
                       double rateamount = Double.parseDouble(rategiven.getText().toString());
                       Double result = ((double)rateamount* taxamount) / 100;
                       Double finalamount=(result + rateamount);
                       TaxInclrate.setText(""+finalamount);
                   }
                   else if(getstock.getText().toString().equals("Pepsi Products"))
                   {
                       taxgiven.setText("5");
                       stockgiven.setText("5");
                       rategiven.setText("140");
                       MRPRate.setText("500");

                       //percentage calculation
                       double taxamount = Double.parseDouble(taxgiven.getText().toString());
                       double rateamount = Double.parseDouble(rategiven.getText().toString());
                       Double result = ((double)rateamount* taxamount) / 100;
                       Double finalamount=(result + rateamount);
                       TaxInclrate.setText(""+finalamount);
                   }
                   else if(getstock.getText().toString().equals("Tang"))
                   {
                       taxgiven.setText("5");
                       stockgiven.setText("23");
                       rategiven.setText("340");
                       MRPRate.setText("450");

                       //percentage calculation
                       double taxamount = Double.parseDouble(taxgiven.getText().toString());
                       double rateamount = Double.parseDouble(rategiven.getText().toString());
                       Double result = ((double)rateamount* taxamount) / 100;
                       Double finalamount=(result + rateamount);
                       TaxInclrate.setText(""+finalamount);
                   }
                   else if(getstock.getText().toString().equals("Top Ramen"))
                   {
                       taxgiven.setText("5");
                       stockgiven.setText("34");
                       rategiven.setText("1230");
                       MRPRate.setText("345");

                       //percentage calculation
                       double taxamount = Double.parseDouble(taxgiven.getText().toString());
                       double rateamount = Double.parseDouble(rategiven.getText().toString());
                       Double result = ((double)rateamount* taxamount) / 100;
                       Double finalamount=(result + rateamount);
                       TaxInclrate.setText(""+finalamount);
                   }
                   else if(getstock.getText().toString().equals("Knorr"))
                   {
                       taxgiven.setText("5");
                       stockgiven.setText("250");
                       rategiven.setText("40");
                       MRPRate.setText("876");



                       //percentage calculation
                       double taxamount = Double.parseDouble(taxgiven.getText().toString());
                       double rateamount = Double.parseDouble(rategiven.getText().toString());
                       Double result = ((double)rateamount* taxamount) / 100;
                       Double finalamount=(result + rateamount);
                       TaxInclrate.setText(""+finalamount);
                   }
                   else if(getstock.getText().toString().equals("Palmolive"))
                   {
                       taxgiven.setText("5");
                       stockgiven.setText("250");
                       rategiven.setText("145");
                       MRPRate.setText("980");

                       //percentage calculation
                       double taxamount = Double.parseDouble(taxgiven.getText().toString());
                       double rateamount = Double.parseDouble(rategiven.getText().toString());
                       Double result = ((double)rateamount* taxamount) / 100;
                       Double finalamount=(result + rateamount);
                       TaxInclrate.setText(""+finalamount);
                   }
                   else if(getstock.getText().toString().equals("Scotch-Brite"))
                   {
                       taxgiven.setText("5");
                       stockgiven.setText("250");
                       rategiven.setText("10");
                       MRPRate.setText("890");

                       //percentage calculation
                       double taxamount = Double.parseDouble(taxgiven.getText().toString());
                       double rateamount = Double.parseDouble(rategiven.getText().toString());
                       Double result = ((double)rateamount* taxamount) / 100;
                       Double finalamount=(result + rateamount);
                       TaxInclrate.setText(""+finalamount);
                   }
                   else if(getstock.getText().toString().equals("Bounty Paper Towls"))
                   {
                       taxgiven.setText("5");
                       stockgiven.setText("250");
                       rategiven.setText("150");
                       MRPRate.setText("1120");

                       //percentage calculation
                       double taxamount = Double.parseDouble(taxgiven.getText().toString());
                       double rateamount = Double.parseDouble(rategiven.getText().toString());
                       Double result = ((double)rateamount* taxamount) / 100;
                       Double finalamount=(result + rateamount);
                       TaxInclrate.setText(""+finalamount);
                   }
                   else if(getstock.getText().toString().equals("Oreo Cookies"))
                   {
                       taxgiven.setText("5");
                       stockgiven.setText("250");
                       rategiven.setText("100");
                       MRPRate.setText("789");

                       //percentage calculation
                       double taxamount = Double.parseDouble(taxgiven.getText().toString());
                       double rateamount = Double.parseDouble(rategiven.getText().toString());
                       Double result = ((double)rateamount* taxamount) / 100;
                       Double finalamount=(result + rateamount);
                       TaxInclrate.setText(""+finalamount);
                   }
                   else if(getstock.getText().toString().equals("Quaker Oats"))
                   {
                       taxgiven.setText("5");
                       stockgiven.setText("250");
                       rategiven.setText("400");
                       MRPRate.setText("1245");

                       double taxamount = Double.parseDouble(taxgiven.getText().toString());
                       double rateamount = Double.parseDouble(rategiven.getText().toString());
                       Double result = ((double)Math.round(rateamount* taxamount) / 100);
                       Double finalamount=(result + rateamount);
                       TaxInclrate.setText(""+finalamount);
                   }
                   else if(getstock.getText().toString().equals("Lays Potato Chips"))
                   {
                       taxgiven.setText("5");
                       stockgiven.setText("250");
                       rategiven.setText("15");
                       MRPRate.setText("900");

                       //percentage calculation
                       double taxamount = Double.parseDouble(taxgiven.getText().toString());
                       double rateamount = Double.parseDouble(rategiven.getText().toString());
                       Double result = ((double)rateamount* taxamount) / 100;
                       Double finalamount=(result + rateamount);
                       TaxInclrate.setText(""+finalamount);
                   }

                }
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```

and based on quantity i want to show the total tax rate and percentage calculation everything is work smoothly until i get this problem what can i do to get the total based on Quantity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
getstock.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(AddOrder.this, ListItem.class);
              Intent intent = getIntent();
               Bundle bd = intent.getExtras();
                if (bd != null) {
                    String getname = (String) bd.get("position");
                    getstock.setText(getname);
                    System.out.println(getname);


                   if(getstock.getText().toString().equals("Stove Top Stuffing")) {
                       taxgiven.setText("12");
                        stockgiven.setText("250");
                        rategiven.setText("598.214");
                        MRPRate.setText("999");


                       //Showqty.setText(addorder.getText().toString());
                       // ShowRate.setText(TaxInclrate.getText().toString());

                        //percentage calculation
                       double taxamount = Double.parseDouble(taxgiven.getText().toString());
                       double rateamount = Double.parseDouble(rategiven.getText().toString());
                       Double result = ((double)Math.round(rateamount* taxamount) / 100);
                       Double finalamount=(result + rateamount);
                       TaxInclrate.setText(""+finalamount);

                                          }
                   else if(getstock.getText().toString().equals("Campell's Soup"))
                   {
                       taxgiven.setText("5");
                       stockgiven.setText("100");
                       rategiven.setText("150");
                       MRPRate.setText("456");

                       //percentage calculation
                       double taxamount = Double.parseDouble(taxgiven.getText().toString());
                       double rateamount = Double.parseDouble(rategiven.getText().toString());
                       Double result = ((double)rateamount* taxamount) / 100;
                       Double finalamount=(result + rateamount);
                       TaxInclrate.setText(""+finalamount);
                   }
                   else if(getstock.getText().toString().equals("Tide"))
                   {
                       taxgiven.setText("5");
                       String a=taxgiven.getText().toString();
                       stockgiven.setText("50");
                       rategiven.setText("200");
                       MRPRate.setText("1000");

                       //percentage calculation
                       double taxamount = Double.parseDouble(taxgiven.getText().toString());
                       double rateamount = Double.parseDouble(rategiven.getText().toString());
                       Double result = ((double)rateamount* taxamount) / 100;
                       Double finalamount=(result + rateamount);
                       TaxInclrate.setText(""+finalamount);
                   }
                 
                }
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```

this is for order class

```
ordernew.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (addordernew.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    addordernew.requestFocus();
                    addordernew.setError("Quantity is not Entered");

                } else {

                    if(getstock.getText().toString().equals("Stove Top Stuffing"))
                    {

                         ShowItem.setText("Stove Top Stuffing");

                         Showqty.setText(addordernew.getText().toString());
                        ShowRate.setText(rategiven.getText().toString());

                        //Calculate total tax and grandtotal
                        int totalPrice=0;
                        int Totaltax=0;
                        int Grandtotal=0;
                        double taxamount = Double.parseDouble(taxgiven.getText().toString());
                        double rateamount = Double.parseDouble(rategiven.getText().toString());
                        Double result = ((double)Math.round(rateamount* taxamount) / 100);
                        Double finalamount=(result + rateamount);
                        TaxInclrate.setText(""+finalamount);

                      totalPrice+= (Double.parseDouble(Showqty.getText().toString()) * Double.parseDouble(rategiven.getText().toString()));
                        Totaltax+= (Double.parseDouble(Showqty.getText().toString()) * ((double)Math.round(rateamount* taxamount) / 100));
                        Grandtotal=totalPrice+Totaltax;
                      totalamtnew.setText(""+totalPrice);
                      taxnewratenew.setText(""+Totaltax);
                        discountnew.setText("0.00");
                       roundoffratenew.setText("0.00");
                     grandtotalnew.setText(""+Grandtotal);





                      // Totaltax += (Double.parseDouble(Showqty.getText().toString()))* Double.parseDouble(taxgiven.getText().toString());

                        //ShowRate.setText(""+totalPrice);

                     //calculate total tax grandtotal


                     // Double result = ((double)rateamount* taxamount) / 100;
//                        taxnewratenew.setText(""+Totaltax);
//                        discountnew.setText("0.00");
//                        roundoffratenew.setText("0.00");
//                        grandtotalnew.setText(""+totalPrice);
                    }

                    if(getstock.getText().toString().equals("Campell's Soup"))
                     {
                        ShowItem.setText("Campell's Soup");
                         ShowRate.setText(rategiven.getText().toString());
                        Showqty.setText(addordernew.getText().toString());
                        //ShowRate.setText(rategiven.getText().toString());


                         //Calculate total tax and grandtotal
                         int totalPrice=0;
                         int Totaltax=0;
                         int Grandtotal=0;
                         double taxamount = Double.parseDouble(taxgiven.getText().toString());
                         double rateamount = Double.parseDouble(rategiven.getText().toString());
                         Double result = ((double)Math.round(rateamount* taxamount) / 100);
                         Double finalamount=(result + rateamount);
                         TaxInclrate.setText(""+finalamount);

                         totalPrice+= (Double.parseDouble(Showqty.getText().toString()) * Double.parseDouble(rategiven.getText().toString()));
                         Totaltax+= (Double.parseDouble(Showqty.getText().toString()) * ((double)Math.round(rateamount* taxamount) / 100));
                         Grandtotal=totalPrice+Totaltax;
                         totalamtnew.setText(""+totalPrice);
                         taxnewratenew.setText(""+Totaltax);
                         discountnew.setText("0.00");
                         roundoffratenew.setText("0.00");
                         grandtotalnew.setText(""+Grandtotal);




                     }
```